# Why can't I use a key function that returns a reference when sorting a vector with sort_by_key?

Tags: generics, rust, lifetime

I'm trying to sort a `Vec<String>` using a key function that returns references to the strings in the vector.  A contrived example is to use the identity function as key function (which of course is useless, but it's the minimal example to reproduce my problem):

```rust
fn key(x: &String) -> &String {
    x
}

fn example(items: Vec<String>) {
    items.sort_by_key(key);
}
```

This gives the following error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> src/lib.rs:6:11
    |
6   |     items.sort_by_key(key);
    |           ^^^^^^^^^^^ lifetime mismatch
    |
    = note: expected associated type `<for<'r> fn(&'r String) -> &'r String {key} as FnOnce<(&String,)>>::Output`
               found associated type `<for<'r> fn(&'r String) -> &'r String {key} as FnOnce<(&String,)>>::Output`
    = note: the required lifetime does not necessarily outlive the empty lifetime
note: the lifetime requirement is introduced here
```

I don't understand why I get this error, so I tried to track this down.  I first implemented my own version of `sort_by_key()`:

```
fn sort_by_key<T, K: Ord>(a: &mut [T], key: fn(&T) -> K) {
    a.sort_by(|x, y| key(x).cmp(&key(y)));
}
```

When trying to call this function, I get what looks like the "opposite" error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/lib.rs:6:29
  |
6 |     sort_by_key(&mut items, key);
  |                             ^^^ one type is more general than the other
  |
  = note: expected fn pointer `for<'r> fn(&'r String) -> &String`
             found fn pointer `for<'r> fn(&'r String) -> &'r String`
```

I can make this code compile by fixing the key type to `&T` instead of using the generic parameter `K`, or by using `&K` instead of `K` as return type for the key function:

```rust
fn sort_by_key_v2<T: Ord>(a: &mut [T], key: fn(&T) -> &T) {
    a.sort_by(|x, y| key(x).cmp(&key(y)));
}

fn sort_by_key_v3<T, K: Ord>(a: &mut [T], key: fn(&T) -> &K) {
    a.sort_by(|x, y| key(x).cmp(&key(y)));
}
```

I also tried adding lifetime annotations, but that only shifted the error around without resolving it.

[Here's the three versions of the `sort_by_key()` function on the Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=a622b2643fcb26e8d119c78f0ecd4f75&version=stable).

Why am I getting these errors?  Is there any way to fix them while keeping the key type `K` completely generic?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

For now, you have to use the "long" form:

```
v.sort_by(|x, y| key(x).cmp(&key(y)));
```

> Why am I getting these errors? Is there any way to fix them?

The cause and fix are one-and-the same: Rust is simply not currently expressive enough to represent what you want. The feature needed is called [*generic associated types* (GATs)](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1598-generic_associated_types.md); previously known as *associated type constructors* (ATCs) or higher-kinded types (HKTs).

From the [associated issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/34162):

> For the `sort_by_key` call to be okay, the lifetime of the input reference [...] needs to be incorporated into `B` to make the return type `&'a str`, but `B` is a type parameter.

I don't know if the signature for `sort_by_key` will be able to be seamlessly moved to a GAT when they are implemented. It seems doubtful at this point, as the `Fn*` traits themselves would likely need to be changed.

---

In similar cases where you control the signature of all the types, you can require that a reference be returned:

```
use std::cmp::Ordering;

struct User {
    name: String,
}

fn compare_keys<T, R>(a: T, b: T, key: impl Fn(&T) -> &R) -> Ordering
where
    for<'a> &'a R: Ord,
{
    let ak = key(&a);
    let bk = key(&b);
    ak.cmp(&bk)
}

fn main() {
    let alice = User {
        name: String::from("alice"),
    };
    let bob = User {
        name: String::from("bob"),
    };

    compare_keys(alice, bob, |u| &u.name);
}
```

This is non-ideal because now you cannot return a non-reference, but there's simply no complete solution until GATs are implemented. You may be able to add a parallel methods like `sort_by` and `sort_by_key`, depending on your case.

Comment: Thanks, I already suspected it's not possible.  I'll read the linked RFC to udnerstand what the error messages mean, and why the error message for the method is different for the one I get for my own version.

Comment: GATs have lended some time ago, but it seems it's still not possible to write a `sort_by_key()` that works as expected (let alone upgrade existing `sort_by_key()` seamlessly). According to [comments in the issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/34162), other nightly features are needed, such as `unboxed_closures` and the next-gen trait solver.

Answer (score 3):

As [@Shepmaster explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47126516/1478356) you cannot have a `sort_by_key` function handling generic associated lifetimes for the return type of the `key` function, but here is a variant for a key function always returning a reference:

```
fn sort_by_key_ref<T, F, K>(a: &mut [T], key: F) 
where
    F: Fn(&T) -> &K,
    K: ?Sized + Ord,
{
    a.sort_by(|x, y| key(x).cmp(key(y)));
}
```

You could also write down the lifetime requirements for the key function:

```
    for<'a> F: Fn(&'a T) -> &'a K,
```

See [example on playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=7ef562914d65a56abf8810f6bf35fea9&version=stable).

Comment: Thanks, I had figured that out (see the third version in my question).  I still like to understand what exactly the error messages mean.

Comment: Huh, totally missed that, sorry. At least the `?Sized` part adds something new :)

Answer (score 2):

The cleanest workaround (IMO) for this that builds on Shepmaster's answer is:

```
fn ref_key<T, K: Ord + ?Sized>(mut f: impl FnMut(&T) -> &K) -> impl FnMut(&T, &T) -> Ordering {
    move |a, b| f(a).cmp(f(b))
}
```

It can be used simply by converting `slice.sort_by_key(key)` to `slice.sort_by(ref_key(key))`.