# Sort a vector with one of many closures depending on a setting

Tags: sorting, rust, closures

I want to get this code to compile:

```
struct Person {
    name: String,
    age: u32,
}

fn main() {
    let sort_by = "age";

    let x = vec![
        Person {
            name: "Peter".to_string(),
            age: 18,
        },
        Person {
            name: "Frank".to_string(),
            age: 55,
        },
    ];

    let key_func;

    if sort_by == "age" {
        key_func = |item: &Person| {
            return &item.age;
        };
    } else if sort_by == "name" {
        key_func = |item: &Person| {
            return &item.name;
        };
    }

    x.sort_by_key(key_func);
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=0508d9d28d53f43b70271e69894eaa25&version=stable&mode=debug)

I know why this does not compile, but I don't know how I can solve it. I tried a couple of different things, including wrapping the closures in `Box::new()`, but I couldn't get it to work.

At first, I wanted to ignore the problem and just move all the sorting logic, including the conditionals, inside a single closure, but then I had to add a reverse sorting option. Because I really would like to use `*_by_key` for simplicity, I tried with `std::cmp::Reverse`, and this happened:

```
use std::cmp::Reverse;

fn main() {
    let reverse = false;

    // ....

    let key_func = |item: &Person| {
        if reverse {
            return Reverse(&item.age);
        } else {
            return &item.age;
        }
    };

    x.sort_by_key(key_func);
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=482bd2290dbaba3ee330f5881b8b6b93&version=stable&mode=debug)

Again, I understand why the error occurs, but I am not sure how to fix it.

Comment: *I know why this does not compile* — and why is that?

Comment: What should happen when `sort_by` is neither "name" or "age"?

Comment: Have you tried this code *without* any conditionals? It doesn't work even in that case.

Comment: If sort_by is neither name or age, let's say it panics.

Comment: To sort a collection you need a comparison function for given collection element's type. This comparison function usually takes two arguments `a` and `b`  which are of the same type. What you are trying to achieve is to hack a single, "generic", lambda instead of providing multiple lambdas with same signature.

Comment: Your algorithm have no way to sort e.g. in descending order for your "age" key. It's hardcoded somewhere in your sort_by_key. Usually standard libraries give user a way to provide lambda taking two parameters and returning boolean value which is stricly defining which one of the parameters is "greater".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already know the problem, so I don't need to explain it again. Here's the code.

```
 let mut cmp_func: Box<Fn(&Person, &Person) -> std::cmp::Ordering> = match sort_by {
    "age" => Box::new(|a, b| a.age.cmp(&b.age)),
    "name" => Box::new(|a, b| a.name.cmp(&b.name)),
    _ => panic!("unknown sort"),
};

if reverse {
    cmp_func = Box::new(move |a, b| cmp_func(a, b).reverse());
}

x.sort_by(|a, b| cmp_func(a, b));
```

Or the more efficient, non-heap-allocating version

```
x.sort_by(|a, b| {
    let ord = match sort_by {
        "age" => a.age.cmp(&b.age),
        "name" => a.name.cmp(&b.name),
        _ => panic!("unknown sort"),
    };

    if reverse {
        ord.reverse()
    } else {
        ord
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

As you seem to recognize, the problem is that `key_func` can only have a single specific type, but each of those two closures have different types.

One is a type that implements `FnMut(&Person) -> &u32` and the other is a type that implements `FnMut(&Person) -> &String`.

Even if they both returned the same type, *even if* they were completely syntactically identical, they would be two distinct types. It's like trying to do `let num: i32 = if predicate { 0 } else { "thing" }`. You could box them into trait objects of the same trait, but boxing `FnMut`s is tricky because `Box<FnMut...>` doesn't implement `FnMut`.

There's an even more fundamental problem: you [can't use `sort_by_key` with functions that return references](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47121985/155423).

One thing you can do is use the more general [`sort_by`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.sort_by), which is `FnMut(&T, &T) -> Ordering` and have logic in there to know what `Ordering` to return based on which fields, perhaps guided by some kind of `SortBy` enum if you really want to.

Another option is to simply call `sort_by_key` within the branches themselves, so that the `Vec` is sorted coming out of it, or if you want to defer the sort, then again maintain some kind of indicator such as a `SortBy` enum which you then use to perform the sort concretely when you actually need to do it.

Comment: Thanks! I really wanted to use `sort_by_key`, since determining the data to sort by in my case involves a bit of ceremony in many cases (fetching related data from auxiliary storage), and the code is just more verbose having to do this twice for `a` and `b. I was also vaguely wondering if sort_by_key could be faster, since the key might be cached, but I suppose looking at the code now this is not the case.

Comment: @miracle2k it sounds like you want the unstable [`sort_by_cached_key`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.sort_by_cached_key) method (which may still not work for your case).