# How to sort a Vec of structs by a String field?

Tags: rust

I'm having difficulty with a seemingly trivial sort by String field. Repro below:

```
struct Dummy {
    x: String,
    y: i8
}

fn main() {
    let mut dummies: Vec<Dummy> = Vec::new();
    dummies.push(Dummy { x: "a".to_string(), y: 1 });
    dummies.push(Dummy { x: "b".to_string(), y: 2 });

    dummies.sort_by_key(|d| d.x); // error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
    dummies.sort_by_key(|d| d.y); // This is fine
}
```

Can someone please explain what exactly is going wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: Very related question: [Why can't I use a key function that returns a reference when sorting a vector with sort_by_key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47121985/why-cant-i-use-a-key-function-that-returns-a-reference-when-sorting-a-vector-wi). This and a basic "cannot move out of borrowed content" answer would explain this question. I didn't want to dupe-hammer -- I want to see if others agree.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

First, let's look at your original error message, then we'll go through a few fixes and try to understand everything.

In the closure that you use in `dummies.sort_by_key(|d| d.x);`, `d` is a reference to a `Dummy` instance. However, the field access `d.x` is the `String` itself. If you wanted to return that `String`, you'd have to give ownership of it to whatever called the closure. But since `d` was just a reference, you can't pass ownership of its data.

One easy fix is to simply clone the string as `dummies.sort_by_key(|d| d.x.clone());`. This makes a copy of the string before returning it in the closure (this is Andra's solution). This works perfectly, but if performance or memory use is an issue, we can avoid the clone.

The idea here is that using the string as the key is wasteful. Really, all we need to know is which of two strings is smaller. If we use the string as a key, then every time the sort function needs to compare two `Dummy`s, it calls the key function on each one and the strings are passed to a (very short) function that simply compares them. If we did the comparison in the same context as the borrow, we'd be able to simply pass the result of the comparison on, rather than the strings.

The solution is the [`sort_by`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.sort_by) method on slices. This allows us to take references to two `Dummy`s and decide if one is smaller than the other. For example we can use it like `dummies.sort_by(|d1, d2| d1.x.cmp(&d2.x));` [(full example here)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=bfd81577c6d456c8070ffa2be51a30e9)

### Addendum

Why can't we use `sort_by_key` without cloning the `String`s? Surely there must be some clever way of using string slices and lifetimes to do it.

Let's look at the signature of [the `sort_by_key` function.](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.sort_by_key)

```
pub fn sort_by_key<K, F>(&mut self, f: F) where
    F: FnMut(&T) -> K,
    K: Ord,
```

The interesting part of this function is not what is there, but what isn't there. The type parameter `K` doesn't depend on the lifetime of the reference passed to `f`.

As the slice is sorted, the key function gets repeatedly called with a reference to a `Dummy` instance. Since the slice is sorted a little between each call, the lifetime of the reference must be very short. If it were longer, it'd get invalidated the next time the elements of the slice were moved around. However, `K` can't depend on that lifetime. That means that whatever our key function is, it can't return anything that depends on the current location of the `Dummy` (e.g. a string slice, a reference, or any other clever construction<sup>1</sup>).

However, we could make `K` depend on the lifetime of whatever is passed to it. The idea here is what's called [*Higher-Rank Trait Bounds*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/hrtb.html). These currently only work with lifetimes (though in theory they could be extended to all type parameters). We could posit another slice method with signature

```
fn sort_by_key_hrtb<T, F, K>(slice: &mut [T], f: F)
where
    F: Fn(&T) -> &K,
    K: Ord,
```

Why does this make things work? In `F: Fn(&T) -> &K,`, the lifetime of the output reference is implicitly the same as (or longer than) the lifetime of the input reference. Desugared, this is `F: for<'a> Fn(&'a T) -> &'a K,`, which says that `f` should be able to take a reference with any lifetime `'a` and return a reference with lifetime (greater than or equal to) `'a`. Now we have a method that works exactly how you wanted to use it (except for a pesky `&`<sup>2</sup>). [(playground link)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a459e00b0ac9f722dbc28d277b8e9f81)

---

1. Actually, there is one (unsafe) clever construction that probably works, but I haven't vetted it. You can use a wrapper around a raw pointer to a `String` and then `impl Ord` for that wrapper so that it dereferences the pointer to do the comparison.<sup>3</sup> The return type for the key function would be `*const String`, so we don't need any lifetimes. This is inherently unsafe though, and I definitely wouldn't recommend it. A (probably) working example is [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2404861f71ac4de39c077efd396a312b).
2. The only reason we need to use `&mut dummies` here is that `sort_by_key_hrtb` isn't actually a slice method. If it were, `dummies` would be automatically borrowed and dereferenced into a slice, so we could call the function like `dummies.sort_by_key_hrtb(|d| &d.x);`.
3. Why a wrapper instead of just a pointer? `*const T` implements `Ord`, but it does so by comparing the addresses rather than the underlying value (if any), which isn't what we want here.

Comment: "Why can't we use sort_by_key without cloning the Strings?" - we can't use the reference here because underlying element is supposed to be moved. The only workaround is to use `&str` instead of `String` in `Dummy` (or something similar)

Comment: @Laney, yup. I'm almost done writing that part of the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation

Comment: "However, `K` can't depend on that lifetime". Can anyone help me understand why?

Answer (score 1):

The [`sort_by_key`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.sort_by_key) function takes ownership of the key:

```
pub fn sort_by_key<K, F>(&mut self, f: F)
```

This is why you are getting [error `E0507`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error-index.html#E0507).

A simple fix will be to store a reference on your struct so `sort_by_key` will not take the ownership of your key.

Then you need to had a lifetime to the referred value so she can be dropped when your struct is gone.

```
struct Dummy<'a> {
    x: &'a str,
    y: i8,
}

fn main() {
    let mut dummies: Vec<Dummy> = Vec::new();
    dummies.push(Dummy { x: "a", y: 1 });
    dummies.push(Dummy { x: "b", y: 2 });

    dummies.sort_by_key(|d| d.x);
    dummies.sort_by_key(|d| d.y);
}
```

Comment: Ho, I did not take the time to read the current answer... But https://stackoverflow.com/a/56106352/4718768 is really complete.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because it's trying to move the `String` from one struct to another struct.

This works fine

```
struct Dummy {
    x: String,
    y: i8
}

fn main() {
    let mut dummies: Vec<Dummy> = Vec::new();
    dummies.push(Dummy { x: "a".to_string(), y: 1 });
    dummies.push(Dummy { x: "b".to_string(), y: 2 });

    dummies.sort_by_key(|d| d.x.clone()); // Clone the string
    dummies.sort_by_key(|d| d.y); // This is fine
}
```

The behavior might looks something like this

```
struct Dummy {
    x: String,
    y: i8
}

fn main() {
    let mut dummies: Vec<Dummy> = Vec::new();
    dummies.push(Dummy { x: "a".to_string(), y: 1 });
    dummies.push(Dummy { x: "b".to_string(), y: 2 });
    let mut temp = Dummy{ x: "c".to_string(), y: 3 };
    temp.x = dummies[0].x; // Error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
}
```

Using `clone()` like the example above

```
struct Dummy {
    x: String,
    y: i8
}

fn main() {
    let mut dummies: Vec<Dummy> = Vec::new();
    dummies.push(Dummy { x: "a".to_string(), y: 1 });
    dummies.push(Dummy { x: "b".to_string(), y: 2 });
    let mut temp = Dummy{ x: "c".to_string(), y: 3 };
    temp.x = dummies[0].x.clone(); // Fine
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to do the sorting using string slices (or avoiding the clone in some other way)?

Comment: Yes, take a look at this https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b2981ac372a7a931b023b6d71fdd8cd4

Comment: What if the strings aren't static? (edit: I also meant that we would still use OP's `Dummy`, which has `String`s. The string slice part was referring to passing a string slice in `sort_by_key`)

Comment: @User: I don't think you can do it with `sort_by_key`, because you would want to return a reference to the string, but you can't do that because `sort_by_key` is already borrowing the Dummy object mutably. However, you can do it with `sort_by`. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4575746783b076a689e4c30be9ff75f0

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Yeah I'm in the process of writing an answer to that effect (and your solution is exactly the same as mine =p).

Comment: @BenjaminLindley using `sort_by` was certainly way better :)