# How to sort a Vec of structs by 2 or multiple fields?

Tags: rust

`example`

```rust
struct MyStruct{
    row: u8,
    column: u8
}

let my_vector = a Vec<MyStruct> with like 100 items in it
```

Lets say I have a simple setup like this ^. I want to sort `my_vector` list of say 100 items by row AND THEN by column so I get my vector looking like `sample 1` instead of `sample 2`.

`sample 1`

```
my_vector = vec![
MyStruct { row: 10, column: 1 },
MyStruct { row: 10, column: 2 },
MyStruct { row: 10, column: 3 }, ]
```

`sample 2`

```
my_vector = vec![
MyStruct { row: 10, column: 3 },
MyStruct { row: 10, column: 1 },
MyStruct { row: 10, column: 2 }, ]
```

Currently I've been working off [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56105305/how-to-sort-a-vec-of-structs-by-a-string-field) which describes how to sort by a single key with the `sort_by_key()` function, but the issue i'm having with that is that I can only sort by a single key, and not by two or multiple keys. This results in problems like `sample 2`, where I get my rows sorted but then my columns in a random order.

**I want both my rows and columns to be ordered. How can I do this?**,  Thanks

Comment: Try the `sort_by` function to use a custom predicate. `my_vector.sort_by(|a, b| ...)`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Since tuples in Rust impl `PartialOrd` with lexicographic comparison, you can use the [`sort_by_key()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.sort_by_key) methods:

```rust
my_vector.sort_unstable_by_key(|item| (item.row, item.column));
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=247008cdf02c485557a2d0fe23328dd9).

Answer (score 5):

You can also implement PartialOrd or Ord for MyStruct <[module std::CMP](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/index.html)>

```
use core::cmp::Ordering;

#[derive(Debug, Eq, PartialEq, Ord)]
struct MyStruct {
    row: u8,
    column: u8,
}

impl PartialOrd for MyStruct {
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Option<Ordering> {
        if self.row == other.row {
            return Some(self.column.cmp(&other.column));
        }
        Some(self.row.cmp(&other.row))
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut my_vector = vec![
        MyStruct { row: 10, column: 3 },
        MyStruct { row: 10, column: 1 },
        MyStruct { row: 10, column: 2 },
    ];
    my_vector.sort();
    println!("{:?}", my_vector);
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c02c3ba6091464fa24a6871ddf5c1606)

Answer (score 5):

By collating the information of the previous two solutions and the help of GitHub Copilot, here is a working solution for a `sort by two keys` sorting method:

Using the `compare` argument on the `sort_by` method for a mutable vector:

```rust
my_vector.sort_by(| a, b | if a.row == b.row {
  a.column.partial_cmp(&b.column).unwrap()
} else {
  a.row.partial_cmp(&b.row).unwrap()
});
```

And using:

```rust
println!("{:#?}", locations);
```

Would output:

```rust
let mut locations = vec![
  Location {
    row: 1,
    column: 1
  },
  Location {
    row: 1,
    column: 2
  },
  Location {
    row: 2,
    column: 1
  },
  Location {
    row: 2,
    column: 2
  }
];
```

Answer (score 2):

I think using `match` is a better alternative because it compares each pair only once. Using `sort_unstable_by` might be a bit better because unstable is faster, and because it is possible to make any comparison go in reverse (descending order) -- simply switch `a` and `b` for that `cmp()` call.

```rust
struct MyStruct {
    row: u8,
    column: u8
}

fn sort(items: &mut [MyStruct]) {
    items.sort_unstable_by(|a, b| {
        match a.row.cmp(&b.row) {
            Ordering::Equal => { a.column.cmp(&b.column) }
            v => { v }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This is just manually implementing [`Ordering::then()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cmp/enum.Ordering.html#method.then).

Answer (score 0):

u can use sort_by()

```
my_vector.sort_by(|a, b| ...);
```

with a and b, u can make condition to return true for sort
[link](https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/rust-cookbook/algorithms/sorting.html)