# How to sort a Vec<(Cow<str>, Cow<str>) by_key without cloning?

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrow-checker

I have a vector of tuples containg key and value pairs and I'd like to sort them by the key. I would like to avoid calling `.to_string()` on the `Cow`s. I can't seem to find a way to do this **without cloning**.

```
use std::borrow::Cow;
fn main() {
    let mut v: Vec<(Cow<str>, Cow<str>)> = vec![("a".into(), "xd".into()), ("0".into(), "xy".into())];
    v.sort_by_key(|(k,_v)| k);
    dbg!(v);
}
```

```
Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error: lifetime may not live long enough
 --> src/main.rs:4:28
  |
4 |     v.sort_by_key(|(k,_v)| k);
  |                    ------- ^ returning this value requires that `'1` must outlive `'2`
  |                    |     |
  |                    |     return type of closure is &'2 Cow<'_, str>
  |                    has type `&'1 (Cow<'_, str>, Cow<'_, str>)`

error: aborting due to previous error

error: could not compile `playground`
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=72a529fa5b0d39997d5e3738db9c291a

#### What I tried

I've tried also creating a function instead of a closure so I could assign the same lifetime to the input arguments and the output ([See playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6789336b7e546d401da44f84148ee870)), but then I get an error about an invalid signature.

A compile-able solution ([See playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=dde673402719613136d2959b06ab0dea)) is to clone the `Cow` which is fine if the `Cow` is `Borrowed`, but if it's not `Borrowed` then why do I need to clone the underlying `String`? Can't I just call `Deref` the `String` into `&str`?

Also tried to match explicitly the different `Cow` variants, but the error is very similar to the first one ([See playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b5c374eff86054023081f8206b1ea4b0)).

#### Error message

Most of all I don't understand the error message: "returning this value requires that `'1` must outlive `'2`". Ok I *accept* that that is required, but why is this an error?

Comment: by_key have some problem with lifetime limitation just use by https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9a14ef4bf49a9aead773152c9761359b

Comment: A dup of [Why can't I use a key function that returns a reference when sorting a vector with sort_by_key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47121985/why-cant-i-use-a-key-function-that-returns-a-reference-when-sorting-a-vector-wi)? The easiest solution is to use `sort_by` with `cmp()` as shown in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I`ll simplify your code a bit for two reasons:

- To make it more idiomatic
- and remove unnecessary code

```
fn main() {
  let mut vector : Vec<(String, String)> = vec![(String::from("a"), String::from("xd")), (String::from("0"), String::from("xy"))];
    
  dbg!(vector);
}
```

So far, so good.

To sort the vector avoiding the method call **.to_string()**, we can do it with the function **sort_by** code (See the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d4d87dcd9a07cb2f954ccf141ee8813f)):

```
vector.sort_by(|(k1, _), (k2, _)| k1.cmp(k2));
```

Note that the function **cmp** does not return a copy of the key but instead the function [cmp](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.Ord.html#tymethod.cmp) returns an Ordering:

```
pub fn cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Ordering
```

The Ordering indicates that a compared value X is [less, equal, greater] than another Y ( X.cmp(Y) ).

Other option is to use the function **partial_cmp**:

```
vector.sort_by(|(k1, _), (k2, _)| k1.partial_cmp(k2).unwrap());
```

The function **partial_cmp** returns an [Option<Ordering>](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/enum.Ordering.html) enumeration. This is because we use the **unwrap** method.

Another option (which does not solve the problem as you want) is using the function **sort_by_key**:

```
vector.sort_by_key(|(k1, _)| String::from(k1));
```

But since this function returns the key, it is a requirement to create a new one to avoid the problem of the lifetime.

Comment: Why the partial cmp + unwrap? The OP wants to sort strings, and they [implement Cmp](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=dfdc2ec963975b1fc94a4cd0d8105ef6). Also, the last part of the answer involves creating a fresh `String` on every access, which is equivalent to (or worse than) the cloning which the OP specifically wants to avoid.

Comment: NaN is a value of the types f64 and f32, and it (and other things like abusing `<`/`>` for posets) is the only reason why PartialCmp even exists. Most types that do not contain an f32 or f64, implement both PartialCmp and Cmp.

Comment: Unlike the custom on some social media sites, you really don't need to annotate edits to a StackOverflow answer with markers like "Edit 1". You will get a better and more readable answer (and a better future resource) if you just go ahead and edit it to be most effective and to the point. In this case you could completely omit the `partial_cmp().unwrap()` part that is not needed to answer the question. (I would also suggest removing the `sort_by_key(String::from)` variant as well.) Of course it's ultimately up to you.

Comment: @user4815162342 Thanks for the comments and advice :)

Answer (score 1):

Just use `sort_by` instead of `sort_by_key`:

```rust
v.sort_by(|(k1, _), (k2, _)| k1.cmp(k2));
```

> Most of all I don't understand the error message

The problem is [`sort_by_key`'s function declaration](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.sort_by_key):

```rust
pub fn sort_by_key<K, F>(&mut self, f: F)
where
    F: FnMut(&T) -> K,
    K: Ord
```

This shows that `sort_by_key` accepts a closure which returns a type `K`, and `&T` doesn't have to outlive `K`. If it were instead defined as

```rust
pub fn sort_by_key<'a, K, F>(&mut self, f: F)
where
    F: FnMut(&'a T) -> K,
    K: Ord + 'a
```

Then it would work in this case. But it isn't, so we have to live with it :/

Comment: Wouldn't the alternative declaration of `sort_by_key()` break other cases? It is my understanding based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47126516/1600898) that the "natural" signature of `sort_by_key()` requires some form of higher-kinded types.

Comment: @user4815162342 Yeah, it wouldn't. `sort_by_key` mutates the array during its operation, meaning it needs exclusive access to the array for the lifetime of `'a`, but the function call also requires that lifetime.

Comment: @user4815162342 Yes, I believe it would break other cases, but I wasn't 100% sure so I didn't include it in the answer.