# Sort Vec<Vec<i32>> in ascending order by the first element, and in descending order by the second element when the first element is equal

Tags: rust

For example [[5,6][2,3][2,5][2,9][1,6]]
First sort by the first element in ascending order, and when one element is equal, sort by the second element in descending order, resulting in [1,6],[2,9],[2,5],[2,3],[5,6]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `sort_by_key()` with a key function that returns a tuple of the first subelement followed by its second subelement wrapped in [`std::cmp::Reverse`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/struct.Reverse.html) to reverse its comparison:

```
v.sort_by_key(|x| (x[0], Reverse(x[1])));
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=536fc4ae217abdb9fbc38771ee6d983f)

If you need to sort with a comparison function rather than a key function (e.g. due to the latter's [limitations when returning references](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47121985/1600898)), a comparator can be nicely expressed using [`Ordering::then_with()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cmp/enum.Ordering.html#method.then_with):

```
v.sort_by(|a, b| a[0].cmp(&b[0]).then_with(|| b[1].cmp(&a[1])));
```

Comment: Extra point for `Reverse`